# How to limit to certain page with TWIG?

Tags: 8, theming

I want this code to appear only when I visit one of the three paths below. How to do this in TWIG ?

```
/product/add/produit
```

or

```
/product/*/edit
```

or

```
/product/*/duplicate
```

The condition below does not work. In addition, you must put the three urls :

```
  {% if '/product/add/produit' in url %}
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-product-list-tags" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Liste des catégories">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <div class="modal-title h4" id="ProductListTags">Liste des catégories</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pb-0">
          {{ drupal_view('product_list_tags', 'block_1') }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the views block in *Block Layout* and configure the visibility to show the block on the three paths.

Then use the block template of the placed views block to add the modal wrapper:

*block--views-block--product-list-tags-block-1.html.twig*

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-product-list-tags" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Liste des catégories">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <div class="modal-title h4" id="ProductListTags">Liste des catégories</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pb-0">

          <div{{ attributes }}>
            {{ content }}
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```